# How to build category structure from large list with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a huge list with about 2 millions records with the following IDs.

```
ID, Cat1, Cat2, Cat3, Cat4, Cat5, Name
```

All cat fields are dependent. So Cat1 is the first parent, Cat2 depends on Cat1 while Cat3 depends on Cat2 and so on.

This way you can imagine of a explorer like tree structure where you have all Cat1 values on top and depending on the chosen Cat1 you see Cat2 etc.

My plan is to build a simple JSON object which represents the complete structure out of all 2 million records.

I know, the easiest way would be to do a simple `SELECT * FROM LIST` and then put each category into the resulting object as long as it doesn't exist. But that would take ages as i would need to go through ALL 2 million records.

What is the fastest way to build that structure?

My second method would be to only do a `SELECT DISTINCT Cat1 ...` on to get all values for Cat1, then do a `SELECT DISTINCT Cat2 ... WHERE Cat1 = X` for each Cat1, then again for each Cat2 (for each Cat1) etc.

But this would end in a lot of SQL queries I need to send to SQL Server.

Is there any other way (less SQL queries) to build my complete structure representing all categories from all 2 million records?

My target is to have a good performance (getting the final structure within seconds ideally).

I will use C# 2013 (.NET) to build the tool connecting to SQL Server.

Comment: Could you add some example desired results, please?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this should link all the matching Id's:

```
select distinct
    t.id
    , t.Cat1
    , t2.Cat2
    , t3.Cat3
    , t4.Cat4
    , t5.Cat5
    , t.Name
from Table t
    inner join table t2
    on t.Cat1 = t2.Cat2
    inner join table t3
    on t2.Cat2 = t3.Cat3
    inner join table t4
    on t3.Cat3 = t4.Cat4
    inner join table t5
    on t4.Cat4 = t5.Cat5
```

Comment: No there is no linking between catalogues. I just want to see what Cat2 values we have for a single Cat1. Imagine you look at it with Excel. Once you set a filter on Cat1 you get records matching with the filter. This way i get a structure on all catalogues. But how to fetch it as fast as possible from sql. Content of each catalogue is independent from the others, so there is no linking.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for:

```
select distinct
    t.Id
    , t2.cat1
    , t3.cat2
    , t4.cat3
    , t5.cat4
    , t6.cat5
    , Name
from Table t
    left join (select distinct cat1 from Table t2) t2
    on t2.Id = t.Id
    left join (select distinct cat2 from Table t3) t3
    on t3.Id = t.Id
    left join (select distinct cat3 from Table t4) t4
    on t4.Id = t.Id
    left join (select distinct cat4 from Table t5) t5
    on t5.Id = t.Id
    left join (select distinct cat5 from Table t6) t6
    on t6.Id = t.Id
```

Or perhaps this:

```
select distinct
    Id
    , name
    , cat1
from Table t
union all
select distinct
    cat2
from Table t
union all
select distinct
    cat3
from Table t
union all
select distinct
    cat4
from Table t
union all
select distinct
    cat5
from Table t
```